# Отправка писем из PHP функцией mail() в виде HTML

Tags: php, email, mime

Делаю форму отправки письма на почту с сайта. Как сделать и что прописать в функции, чтобы письма приходили на почту в виде html?

Кроме того, даже простой текст приходит в письме на абракадабре , это на mail.ru почте, а на yandex.ru всё нормально.

Как решить вопрос?

Код такой:

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'mail@mail.ru'; //Сюда введите Ваш email
    $body = "Вам поступил заказ с сайта Вектор-М на: \nПакет $vid_pack $color_view \n\nПараметры: \n\nШирина:$width мм \n\nДлина:$length мм \n\nТолщина:$thickness мкм \n\nКоличеством: $quantity шт.\nпо цене $price руб/шт. на общую сумму $summa руб. \n\nКонтактные данные: \n\nИмя:$contactname \n\nТелефон:$phone \n\nE-mail:$email \n\nПримечание:\n$message\n
";
    $headers = 'From: Форма заказа с сайта Вектор-М <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
} else {
    exit ("<p>Вы заполнили не все обязательные поля, вернитесь назад и заполните все обязательные поля.<br><input name='back' type='button' value='Вернуться назад' onclick='javascript:self.back();'></p>");
    }
}
```

Comment: добавьте у себя в коде
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251' . "\r\n";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$to = 'user@example.com';
$subject = 'Заголовок';
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Заголовок</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Привет!</p>
</body>
</html>
';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Reminder <Reminder@example.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое всё отлично работает, и на mail.ru тоже ..., однако в почтовом клиенте опера в поле от всё равно абракадабру пишет

Answer (score 2):

В заголовке письма нужно указать, что это именно text/html , по умолчанию шлется как обычный текст. А то, что абра-кадабра, так тоже - в заголовке письма нужно явно указать кодировку. Погуглите на тему **mime headers**.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="post" action="formmail.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlendoded">
```

enctype определяет формат отправляемых данных при использовании метода передачи данных post. По умолчанию используется **application/x-www-form-urlendoded**