# Как отправить выбранные чекбоксы на емейл, помогите новичку

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста:

Без вмешательства сервера!

Документ только html, в котором находится таблица с полями. У каждого поля есть "чекбокс". Выбрав нужные "чекбоксы", отправляем на е-мейл.

У меня есть index.html. В index.html есть таблица из access. Чекбокс вставил вручную. Внизу таблицы имеется кнопка "отправить".

Задача следующая:

Мне необходимо отмеченные поля чекбоксами, отправить из этой же страницы (html) на е-мейл, нажав на кнопку отправки. 
Помогите реализовать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из браузера нельзя отправить email без участия сервера. Протоколы отправки - SMTP / IMAP - не поддерживаются браузерами (потому что браузер - это браузер, а не почтовый клиент).

Максимум что можно сделать без сервера - сформировать и открыть ссылку вида `mailto:someone@example.com&body=some%20body&subject=some%20subject`, по которой откроется почтовый клиент на стороне пользователя c заранее заполненным письмом. И как-то убедить пользователя нажать кнопку "Отправить".

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ. Начну пробовать делать это с помощью пхп . Посмотрим на ответы ещё, может у кого-то есть идеи ?) Быть может, Вы мне подскажете где о этом почитать ?

Comment: @PW_31 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29107/